# Open Leafleat popup from external link

Tags: jquery, leaflet

I'm trying to open popup of my LeafLeat map with a external link (outside of map)...

I found this solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/abenrob/ZkC5M/

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.495, -0.09], 15);
var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
var osmLayer = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {
  maxZoom: 19,
  attribution: 'Map data © OpenStreetMap contributors'
});
map.addLayer(osmLayer);
var markers = [];
var marker1 = L.marker([51.497, -0.09],{title:"marker_1"}).addTo(map).bindPopup("Marker 1");
markers.push(marker1);
var marker2 = L.marker([51.495, -0.083],{title:"marker_2"}).addTo(map).bindPopup("Marker 2");
markers.push(marker2);
var marker3 = L.marker([51.49, -0.097],{title:"marker_3"}).addTo(map).bindPopup("Marker 3");
markers.push(marker3);

function markerFunction(id){
  for (var i in markers){
    var markerID = markers[i].options.title;
    if (markerID == id){
      markers[i].openPopup();
    };
  }
}

$("a").click(function(){
  markerFunction($(this)[0].id);
});
```

but it doesn't work with the latest version of leafleat.

Does anybody know any solution?

Thanks

Comment: It works for me... https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/bam/edit?html,output